# Ruby regex to split text

Tags: ruby, regex

I am using the below regex to split a text at certain ending punctuation however it doesn't work with  quotes.

```
text = "\"Hello my name is Kevin.\" How are you?"
text.scan(/\S.*?[.．.！!?？]/)

=> ["\"Hello my name is Kevin.", "\" How are you?"]
```

My goal is to produce the following result, but I am not very good with regex expressions. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
=> ["\"Hello my name is Kevin.\"", "How are you?"]
```

Comment: The input is not a valid english text, as your example, or you are picking a bad example?

Comment: @mbratch thanks for the link. However, `text.split(/([.．.！!?？])\s+/)` yields `=> ["\"Hello my name is Kevin.\" How are you?"]` which is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Your question is not clear. The result is exactly what you stated that you want; the string is split at a punctuation. What is the rule that makes you want otherwise?

Comment: Sorry, the "simpler form" I showed wasn't quite right. The longer form in the link works, and is similar to what Casimir gave for an answer.

Comment: @mbratch thanks, I'll check that out as well. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
text.scan(/"(?>[^"\\]+|\\{2}|\\.)*"|\S.*?[.．.！!?？]/)
```

The idea is to check for quoted parts before. The subpattern is a bit more elaborated than a simple `"[^"]*"` to deal with escaped quotes (* see at the end to a more efficient pattern).

pattern details:

```
"             # literal: a double quote
(?>           # open an atomic group: all that can be between quotes
    [^"\\]+   # all that is not a quote or a backslash
  |           # OR
    \\{2}     # 2 backslashes (the idea is to skip even numbers of backslashes)
  |           # OR
    \\.       # an escaped character (in particular a double quote)
)*            # repeat zero or more times the atomic group
"             # literal double quote
|             # OR
\S.*?[.．.！!?？]
```

to deal with single quote to you can add: `'(?>[^'\\]+|\\{2}|\\.)*'|` to the pattern (the most efficient), but if you want make it shorter you can write this:

```
text.scan(/(['"])(?>[^'"\\]+|\\{2}|\\.|(?!\1)["'])*\1|\S.*?[.．.！!?？]/)
```

where `\1` is a backreference to the first capturing group (the found quote) and `(?!\1)` means not followed by the found quote.

*(*)* instead of writing `"(?>[^"\\]+|\\{2}|\\.)*"`, you can use `"[^"\\]*+(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*+"` that is more efficient.

Comment: can you explain this regex please. It will be really great for noobs like us

Comment: Thanks! If I also wanted to include single quotes, is there a more suscinct way to write it than just having another or statement?

Answer (score 1):

Add optional quote (`["']?`) to the pattern:

```
text.scan(/\S.*?[.．.！!?？]["']?/)
# => ["\"Hello my name is Kevin.\"", "How are you?"]
```